# How to write the proof for this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $a \neq 0$. Use a proof by contradiction to show that if $(a \nmid (bc))$ then $(a \nmid b)$. The symbol $\nmid$ stands for "does not divide".

I got the layout, but I don't know how to go about this.

```
Assume x in D:
  Assume P(x)
    Assume ¬Q(x)
       What to do here?
   Then Q(x)
 Then P(x) implies Q(x):
Then for all x in D, P(x) implies Q(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a \nmid bc$, but $a \mid b$. Since $a \mid b$, $b=ma$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $b=ma$. Now by our supposition, $a \nmid bc \Rightarrow a \nmid mac$. But $\frac{mac}{a}=mc \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so $a \mid bc$. This is a contradiction.

---

In general terms of your layout abstraction, the above would go as follows:

To prove $P \Rightarrow Q$:

1. Assume $(P \wedge \neg Q)$ (the negation).
2. Use $\neg Q$ to directly prove $\neg P$.
3. Hence $(P \wedge \neg P)$, the contradiction.
4. Therefore $P \Rightarrow Q$.

---

As a condensed sketch starting with the negation of the implication and ending with that which was to be proven:
$$(P \wedge \neg Q) \Rightarrow \neg Q \Rightarrow \ldots \Rightarrow \neg P \Rightarrow (P \wedge \neg P) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow Q).$$